# Internet Explorer Tracking Protection Prevents JQuery and Other Libraries from Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-api, do-not-track

It appears that Internet Explorer blocks certain common javascript pages hosted by google from loading (including jquery and google fonts). Is there any way to avoid this? Do I have to refrain from using `googleapis.com` javascript on my site?

Below is a screenshot from the IE developer console:
[image: Internet Explorer Tracking Protection]

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in IE called Tracking Protection List (TPL) which blocks your scripts, more details can be found here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/12/07/ie9-and-privacy-introducing-tracking-protection-v8.aspx

You can however personalized your TPL:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/tracking-protection-list-internet-explorer

OR

Host copies of the scripts and fonts within your domain

Comment: So this feature effectively renders caching on `googleapis.com` useless?